# Something wrong Ubuntu 19.10. My terminal is not working properly

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, gnome-terminal

I just upgraded my ubuntu version to 19.10 today but got some serious problems. I have no idea why it is not working.

1. From the main screen, I can't find "open terminal" button when I click right button. Also, it seems that there are many buttons missing.
2. I can't drag from the main screen.
3. The terminal theme is all white. Even I tried to change the preference, the colors are not changing TT. (I set to Tangodark at the preference but nothing have changed. TT)

[Picture of what I am facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ti8Fm.jpg)

This is the screenshots explaining problems above. Those anyone know why this is the problem and how can I fix this?

Comment: Also, I just found out that there is no way to open file managers like nautilus. I can open files by terminal but can't see by GUI

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this qualifies as an answer but since I can't add comment here it is:

1 and 2. I think this is normal behavior, "open terminal" and other options like "New Folder" should appear when you right-click on file browser context. Related: 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1137600/trash-icon-and-files-have-disappeared-from-the-desktop-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-1

3. In the screenshot you have "Unnamed" is the selected profile, not "aaa"